# Generated C code (from Pro*C) contains absolute path

Tags: absolute-path, oracle-pro-c

I am auditing C code that has been generated from [Pro*C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro%2aC) ages ago, and I have found this:

```
static const struct sqlcxp sqlfpn =
{
    33,
    "d:¥¥VS¥¥Projects¥¥SOMEDIR¥¥somefile.pc"
};
```

Absolute paths in code are forbidden by our quality rules.
Is Oracle's Pro*C→C converter really doing such a bad thing, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used by the undocumented `sqlctx()` function, and I don't think you can stop Pro*C generating this structure. I'm not sure it's intrinsically a bad thing, it's just something that appears in the generated code and is used internally by Oracle.

You'll also see the full path of the original `.pc` file in `#line` directives, if you have the `LINES` [precompiler option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_10opt.htm) turned on. (This allows the C compiler to report errors against the line number in the original source file, which is much handier than trying to figure it out from the line in the generated source).

I suspect, but I'm not entirely sure, that it's included in `sqlctx()` so the value can be used for internal errors too, and possibly for debugging.

From a coding standards perspective, having full paths in your source is probably considered a bad thing because you'd have to touch the code if the paths changed; but that seems rather moot in generated code as the new path will be picked up automatically on next build. However, if there are other reasons - a blanket security requirement to reveal minimal build information maybe - then you should be aware that the full path will also appear in the final binary. (In Linux, `strings` shows the full path; no idea about a Windows equivalent but I'd imagine it's there somewhere). If you're auditing generated code then it sounds like a security rather than practical thing.

You can avoid the full path, if it really matters, by moving into the source directory and just giving the file name with no path in the `iname`, i.e.

```
cd d:\VS\Projects\SOMEDIR
proc iname=somefile.pc ...
```

instead of

```
proc iname=d:\VS\Projects\SOMEDIR\somefile.pc
```

Comment: I was indeed suspecting it was to display debugging information, I am relieved to get your confirmation :-)

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul - I'm not 100% sure that's what `sqlctx()` uses it for, but I can't think of any other reason it would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a reason:
e10825 p313:

Note: The sqlctx hash value is generated based on the INAME
parameter passed to the Pro*C/C++ command. This can cause issues
in the applications where files having the same name are stored in
different directories containing different functions and the build
scripts are sent to the physical directory to precompile the program.
As a result, there is no need to place the makefiles at a higher level
and precompile files using their pathnames.